# Spark structured streaming with Kafka JSON input formatting in JAVA

Tags: java, json, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Found several ideas for Scala but unable to implement in Java with success, hence posting as a new question.

I need to format input JSON in "value" column streaming from Kafka topic

```
Dataset<Row> output = df.select(functions.from_json(df.col("value"), schema));

StructType schema = new StructType();
schema.add("Id", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("Type", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("KEY", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("condition", DataTypes.IntegerType);
schema.add("seller_Id", DataTypes.IntegerType);
schema.add("seller_Name", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("isActive", DataTypes.BooleanType);
```

Reached up to the point to see below being printed on console sink -

```
StreamingQuery query = output.writeStream().format("console").start();

+-------------------------+ 
|     jsontostructs(value)|
+-------------------------+
|                    []   |
+-------------------------+
```

Please advise how to get individual columns from this Structure.

Answer (score 1):

So basically need to use "from_json" function in conjunction with schema.json() function to get String schema (similar to what Filip mentioned above in scala). Hope it helps someone.

```
StructType schema = new StructType();
schema.add("Id", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("Type", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("KEY", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("condition", DataTypes.IntegerType);
schema.add("seller_Id", DataTypes.IntegerType);
schema.add("seller_Name", DataTypes.StringType);
schema.add("isActive", DataTypes.BooleanType);

Dataset<Row> output = df.select(from_json(df.col("value"), DataType.fromjson(schema.json())).as("data")).select("data.*");
```

the last select will flatten out the structure into the field defined under schema directly.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a schema defined for your JSON message...

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("test")
    .getOrCreate()

val df: DataFrame = sparkSession
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")...

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sparkSession.implicits._

val ds = df.select($"value" cast "string" as "json")
        .select(from_json($"json", schema) as "data")
        .select("data.*")
```

Note that `append` output mode isn't supported when you're messing w/ streaming aggregations on streaming DF/DS without watermarking, so in case you wanna go crazy with aggregations remember to update output to something along the following lines:

```
val query = aggregations
           .writeStream
           .outputMode("complete")
           .format("console")
           .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: APIs are slightly different between scala and java, posting the solution I found later below.

Comment: @AbhishekN +1 to the solution you've shared on this